# hibernate search indexing one entity to two different indexes

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, indexing, hibernate-search

I want to index one entity to different indexes depending on the situation.

For example, if i have a Fruit entity like below

```
@Indexed
public class Fruit {

    @NumericField(forField = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO)
    private String name;
}
```

Is it possible to index to different indexes according to the name value?

name = "apple" -> index_1

name = "orange" -> index_2

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend that you reconsider whether you really need this.

If the data sets for each "fruit name" are quite different (some fields only ever filled for one "fruit name", or their content is much larger for one "fruit name"), it can make sense. I would personally reconsider the type hierarchy, but that's not always something you can control.
That being said, be aware that currently you will still have to use the same mapping (same fields) for both "fruit names"; you will just have two different indexes with potentially different low-level settings (storage options, ...).

If the data sets for each "fruit name" are similar (same fields, similar content, frequently queried together), there's little to be gained functionally from splitting them across two indexes: you'll just have to worry about twice as many files when backing up, etc.
You may get performance improvements, but then again you could get similar results by tuning the [merge settings](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#lucene-indexing-performance) to control how many segments compose your index.

If you really need to partition your data based on the "fruit name"... here's how to do it. The feature is called "sharding":

- [See here for Hibernate Search 5](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#advanced-features-dynamic-sharding). This will work well with the Lucene integration, but I'm unsure about the Elasticsearch integration.
- [See here for Hibernate Search 6](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-lucene-configuration-sharding). This will only work with the Lucene integration.

Hibernate Search 6 will, in a future update, have a dedicated feature to partition data of a single type based on a property; see [HSEARCH-3683](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3683). For now you can only use routing/sharding.